# doctrine query error reporting

Tags: doctrine

I was wondering if it is possible to output a doctrine error, an equivalent to something like:

> die(mysql_error());

I am asking because of a form script that is not saving data, but not returning an error either. And i have no idea what Doctrine is doing 'behind the scenes'.

Much appreciated
J

Comment: how about using [SQL Logger](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/configuration.html#sql-logger-optional)?

Answer (score 0):

```php
class FileSqlLogger implements Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\SQLLogger {

    private $log_dir = '/var/www/logs/Doctrine/queries';

    public function startQuery($sql, array $params = null, array $types = null)
    {
        $now = new DateTime;
        $file_name = "{$this->log_dir}/{$now->format('d-m-Y')}.log";

        if (is_writable($this->log_dir))
        {
            file_put_contents($file_name, "{$now->format('H:i:s')}: Executing query '{$sql}' with parameters " . implode(', ', $params));
        }
        else
        {
            die('Error: Unable to write to the Doctrine log file!');
        }
    }

}
```

I haven’t tested that and I have no idea if it will work, but I think it should help get you in the right direction.